# Scala sealed trait - replicate Enumeration `withName` method

Tags: scala

I'm trying to refactor an `Enumeration` to a sealed trait with concrete classes because I need to pack more functionality into them. With the sealed trait, I'd like to have functionality similar to `Enumeration`'s `withName(String)` method. I've come up with the following code to do so and am looking for feedback:

```
sealed trait Foo {
  def name: String
}

object Foo {
  case object FooA extends Foo {
    override val name: String = "a"
  }

  case object FooB extends Foo {
    override val name: String = "b"
  }

  val values = Seq(FooA, FooB)

  def withName(name: String): Option[Foo] = {
    values.find(value => value.name.equals(name))
  }
}
```

I can then use the `withName(String)` method to get the corresponding concrete object of type `Foo` as an `Option`:

```
val testFooAName = "a"
val testFooA = Foo.withName(testFooAName) // Will yield Some(FooA)

testFooA match {
    case Some(Foo.FooA) => println("Matched Foo.FooA!")
    case Some(Foo.FooB) => print("Matched Foo.FooB!")
}

val testFooNoneName = "none"
val testFooNone = Foo.withName(testFooNoneName) // Will yield None

Output:
Matched Foo.FooA!
```

Is this approach correct?

Comment: There are only two elements, but still: it's an `O(n)` lookup instead of an `O(1)` lookup... Set up a private `Map` for `withName` method. Furthermore, it looks as if it could belong to Code Review Stack Exchange.

Comment: but still you have to do `values.find(_.name == name)` . We need set of strings to directly compare

Comment: You can have a look at https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum

Comment: Map is one option for O(1) lookup, but since the map is private anyways you can also avoid the space overhead if you do `name match {...}` and return one of the objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it looks fine

Minor simplification: Have a map for fast lookup

```
val values = Seq(FooA, FooB)
val fastLookup = values.map(v => v.name -> v).toMap

def withName(name: String): Option[Foo] = fastLookup.get(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a handy library by `beachape` which can be used to provide some of the functionality of enums to your `sealed trait`

the package you need to include in your sbt is:

```
"com.beachape" %% "enumeratum" % "1.5.15"
```

then extend your your object with the `Enum` like so:

```
import enumeratum._

sealed trait Foo

object Foo extends Enum[Foo] {
  case object FooA extends Foo 
  case object FooB extends Foo 
}
```

The you can use the `withName` function (amongst others) to get the sealed trait you want:

```
Foo.withName("FooA")
```